# Region of Interest algorithm (square)

Tags: algorithm, opencv

In opencv there is a data type name Rect, one of his constructors are like this:

Rect(Point pt1, Point pt2).

And then you can crop the Mat, using it's method

Mat.submat(Rect roi).

With this method you take a square created from two points, croping the Mat.

I'm using another data type so I can't use opencv, and I need to know how this algorithm is implemented or where I can read more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to loop through the pixels and copy them over, see below. OpenCV certainly uses more optimised and sophisticated code - you'll have to trawl through the source code to find the implementation. The snippet below should help if you're looking for a straightforward solution without worrying about efficiency.

```
YourImageType ExtractSubImage(YourImageType sourceImage, RECT roi)
{
    YourImageType destImage;
    <Allocate destImage with size same as roi>

    for (int rowSrc = roi.top, rowDst = 0, pixelDst = 0; rowSrc <= roi.bottom; rowSrc++, rowDst++)
    {
        int pixelSrc = sourceImage.width * rowSrc + roi.left;
        for (int colSrc = roi.left, colDst = 0; colSrc <= roi.right; colSrc++, colDst++, pixelSrc++, pixelDst++)
        {
            destImage.buffer(pixelDst) = sourceImage.buffer(pixelSrc);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```